# Audio Source in Vuforia Area target scene in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, vuforia

I am having trouble playing an audio source in a unity scene using a vuforia area target.  I am just learning Unity and Vuforia with not much experience.  I wrote a basic unity script without using the calls for Vuforia.  I am assuming I need the "DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs" included.  Vuforia documentation is not to descriptive and I am looking for some guidance if available.